# Real-Time Push stopped working

Tags: foursquare

I'm using the Foursquare Real-Time API and have got it working successfully with a Django application I've created.

I've been using it for a few days now and it seemed to be working fine. Everytime someone checked into a venue that I managed, my Django app would receive a Push notification successfully.

But today it stopped working, The Foursquare servers don't seem to be sending the Real-Time Push to my server. I can send the 'resent push' and 'test push' from the admin application page in Foursquare. But when a user tries to check-in using a native app, the Foursquare servers don't seem to push it. Does the servers only push once per user per day? Should they push everytime a user checks in, even if they check in more than once in a given day?

Cheers

Boppyer:-)

Comment: Did you you find the reason? In my app it never worked, I can manually send last checkins to my app (using 'Resend a recent push') but they are never pushed automatically

Comment: I would also like to know whether you found a reason for this - my app was receiving push updates, then they seemed to stop without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

They push every time an authorizing user checks in. Check foursquare.com/oath to see if foursquare reports errors trying to send push notifications to your app.